# Ionic v4 back button query params

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

The `ion-back-button` navigates back to the correct URL but it omits previous query params that were also in that URL. Is there a way to restore those query params?

In my specific use case, the query params contain an `ID` that is needed to fetch data for that page. When you navigate to that page without that `ID` it doesn't know what to show.

Comment: The component is actually left alive in my case so I do not need those params again to fetch the data, but it would be interesting none the less if there is a way to preserve those params even when clicking the ion-back-button.